# Is the page cache managed separately for each cgroup or is it managed globally?

Tags: linux, containers, cgroups

Is the page cache managed separately for each cgroup (per container) or is it managed globally?

In other words, is each container managing the page cache according to the vm.dirty_background_ratio and dirty_writeback_interval values?